# Mocking - How do I raise exception on the caller?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Suppose this is the code

```
def move(*args, **kwargs):   
    try:
        shutil.move(source, destination)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

and in my tests.py

```
@patch.object(shutil, 'move')
def test_move_catch_exception(self, mock_rmtree):
    ''' Tests moving a target hits exception. '''
    mock_rmtree.side_effect = Exception('abc')
    self.assertRaises(Exception, move,
                             self.src_f, self.src_f, **self.kwargs)
```

It said this

```
  File "unittests.py", line 84, in test_move_catch_exception
    self.src_f, self.src_f, **self.kwargs)
AssertionError: Exception not raised
```

If I assert on `mock_rmtree` it will pass. How can I assert on the caller (in this case, the function `move`)?

---

As **aquavitae** pointed out, the primary reasons was copy-paste error, and also I was asserting a tuple in the beginning. Always asseert with the right return type...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You've got a typo in your example, missing a `'`.

Its not entirely clear what you're asking, but if I understand you correctly, you're asking how to test that a raised exception is caught inside `move`.  One problem is that you're patching `shutil.rmtree`, not `shutil.move`, but you can't be certain that`shutil.rmtree` will ever be called.  `shutil.move` only actually calls `shutil.rmtree` if it successfully copies a directory, but since you're copying `self.src_f` to itself, this doesn't happen.  This is not a very good way of patching it though, because the assumption that `shutil.move` will call `shutil.rmtree` at all is not guaranteed and is implementation dependent.

As for how to test it, simply check that the return value is as expected:

```
@patch.object(shutil, 'move')
def test_move_catch_exception(self, mock_move):
    ''' Tests moving a target hits exception. '''
    e = OSError('abc')
    mock_move.side_effect = e
    returns = move(self.src_f, self.src_f, **self.kwargs)
    assert returns == (False, e)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I apologized for the confusions. It was a copy-paste error which I didn't catch. Yes I am patching move rather than rmtree. I edited the post accordingly. You are correct about my careless here. Thanks a lot.