# Mocking a function to raise an Exception to test an except block

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, mocking, python-mock

I have a function (`foo`) which calls another function (`bar`). If invoking `bar()` raises an `HttpError`, I want to handle it specially if the status code is 404, otherwise re-raise.

I am trying to write some unit tests around this `foo` function, mocking out the call to `bar()`. Unfortunately, I am unable to get the mocked call to `bar()` to raise an Exception which is caught by my `except` block.

Here is my code which illustrates my problem:

```
import unittest
import mock
from apiclient.errors import HttpError


class FooTests(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('my_tests.bar')
    def test_foo_shouldReturnResultOfBar_whenBarSucceeds(self, barMock):
        barMock.return_value = True
        result = foo()
        self.assertTrue(result)  # passes

    @mock.patch('my_tests.bar')
    def test_foo_shouldReturnNone_whenBarRaiseHttpError404(self, barMock):
        barMock.side_effect = HttpError(mock.Mock(return_value={'status': 404}), 'not found')
        result = foo()
        self.assertIsNone(result)  # fails, test raises HttpError

    @mock.patch('my_tests.bar')
    def test_foo_shouldRaiseHttpError_whenBarRaiseHttpErrorNot404(self, barMock):
        barMock.side_effect = HttpError(mock.Mock(return_value={'status': 500}), 'error')
        with self.assertRaises(HttpError):  # passes
            foo()

def foo():
    try:
        result = bar()
        return result
    except HttpError as error:
        if error.resp.status == 404:
            print '404 - %s' % error.message
            return None
        raise

def bar():
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

I followed the [Mock docs](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html#quick-guide) which say that you should set the `side_effect` of a `Mock` instance to an `Exception` class to have the mocked function raise the error.

I also looked at some other related StackOverflow Q&As, and it looks like I am doing the same thing they are doing to cause and Exception to be raised by their mock.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10310532/346561
- [How to use Python Mock to raise an exception - but with Errno set to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20547038/346561)

Why is setting the `side_effect` of `barMock` not causing the expected `Exception` to be raised? If I am doing something weird, how should I go about testing logic in my `except` block?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your exception *is* being raised, but I'm not sure how you are setting the `resp.status` code there. Where does `HTTPError` come from?

Comment: @MartijnPieters `HttpError` is a class defined in [Google's `apiclient` lib](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) which we use in GAE. It's `__init__` is defined with the params `(resp, content)` so I was attempting to create a mock instance for the response, with the appropriate status code specified.

Comment: Right, so it is [this class](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/errors.py#L35-L63); but you don't need to user `return_value` then; `resp` is not being *called*.

Comment: I tried my code again without using `HttpError` and instead tried using just a regular `Exception` instance. This works perfectly. This means that it must have something to do with how I am configuring the `HttpError` instance, probably related to how I am creating a `Mock` instance for the response.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Your mock is raising the exception just fine, but the `error.resp.status` value is missing. Rather than use `return_value`, just tell `Mock` that `status` is an attribute:

```
barMock.side_effect = HttpError(mock.Mock(status=404), 'not found')
```

Additional keyword arguments to `Mock()` are set as attributes on the resulting object.

I put your `foo` and `bar` definitions in a `my_tests` module, added in the [`HttpError` class](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/errors.py#L35-L63) so I could use it too, and your test then can be ran to success:

```
>>> from my_tests import foo, HttpError
>>> import mock
>>> with mock.patch('my_tests.bar') as barMock:
...     barMock.side_effect = HttpError(mock.Mock(status=404), 'not found')
...     result = my_test.foo()
... 
404 - 
>>> result is None
True
```

You can even see the `print '404 - %s' % error.message` line run, but I think you wanted to use `error.content` there instead; that's the attribute `HttpError()` sets from the second argument, at any rate.

Comment: the `side_effect` is the key part

Comment: What does HttpError(mock.Mock(status=404), 'not found') do? For me, it didn't set the status code to 404, it's still None.

Comment: @Yang: are you using the [`google-api-client` exception class](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/25fba648ea647b62f2a6edc54ae927c1ed381b45/googleapiclient/errors.py#L35-L86)? I can't help you without any detail on what exactly you are doing. The `mock.Mock(status=404)` expression creates a mock object that has a `.status` attribute, which `HttpError` stores as the `resp` attribute. In the question, that is then accessed as `error.resp.status`.