# How to raise an exception in pytest?

Tags: python, django, pytest, django-tests

I have written a code in views.py

```
def fun():
    try:
         --Do some operation--
    except OSError:
         --Do something else--
```

And I have written a test case to cover total functionality of the code. To test the "except" part I have written the following code where it will raise "OSError",

```
with pytest.raises(OSError):
    response = client.post(reverse('my_views_funurl'), follow=True)
```

But, I am getting this error

```
response = client.post(reverse('my_views_funurl'), follow=True)
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE
```

How to raise "OSError" to cover the except part in test cases.
By the way I am using django-framework

Comment: you can operate on a file that doesnt exist that will give you oserror ex: os.remove('file') but file doesnt exist.

Comment: You mock the function that should raise the exception and give the exception as side effect. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide

Answer (score 0):

Best thing would probably be to just mock the method to throw the exception you need, instead of going through all the trouble of actually creating conditions in which `OSError` would be thrown. A toy example:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

def something():
    ...

something = Mock(side_effect=OSError('Your error text'))

>>> something()
>>> Traceback (most recent call first):
>>> ...
>>> OSError: Your error text
```

Now as I said, it's only a toy example, so for your own project with different structure and all you will most likely need a bit different setup (given the information you provided it's hard to know how exactly it will look). For example, if you're expecting that some call will throw an `OSError` exception inside your `fun()`, then you will need to mock the call in the module `fun()` is located in. Good places to start reading up on mocks:

1. [Docs quick guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide)
2. [Patch documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) (pay particularly close attention to ['where to patch'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id5) part)
3. [Useful in-depth example on stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305406/mocking-a-function-to-raise-an-exception-to-test-an-except-block). As it is a bit more sophisticated than my proof-of-concept example, it will probably resemble what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am getting the following error:            with pytest.raises(OSError):
>           response = client.post(reverse('hard_delete_drive', kwargs = {'slug':doc.slug}), follow=True)
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE

Comment: What method exactly should throw the exception you are expecting? Is it `hard_delete_drive()`, or something inside the view? What module is it in?

Comment: `hard_delete_drive()`is a function in views.py and I used try-except method to catch the errors. I am catching `OSError` and `IOError` in this function. I want to write a test to cover the lines uner `OSError` and `IOError`. For that I am raising error using `with pytest.raises(IOError):` but I am getting `DID NOT RAISE`.

Comment: Which method calls in `hard_delete_drive()` are susceptible to `OSError`/`IOError`? You will most likely need to mock them. Could you edit your original question to include them, so that I could attempt to reproduce what you're trying to achieve on my machine?

Comment: The question is about "pytest" not "unittests".

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from using `unittest.mock` (included in standard Python library) along with `pytest` if you so wish. As far as I know, `mocker` that you use in your answer comes from `pytest-mock` package, which itself is a thin wrapper around `mock` package (included in Python 3.3 onwards as `unittest.mock`). Since using `pytest` doesn't necessarily imply using `pytest-mock` and the question did not mention `mocker`, my answer relies on tools included in standard Python installation.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this with "**pytest**" would be to provide the "**side_effect**" parameter to **patch()** with your expected **Exception**. Example:

```
def your_test_function(mocker):
    mocker.patch(
        "function.being.mocked",
        side_effect=OSError()
    )
    with pytest.raises(OSError):
        function.being.mocked()
```